# Quarkus - Dynamically add / remove REST Endpoint at runtime not possible

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, resteasy

Quarkus automatically adds all REST Services and serves them, which is a great feature if the application itself is intended to run in an 'all or nothing' manner. We are currently investigating how to migrate a large enterprise application to Quarkus. Our application can be configured to run in separated jvm and a central configuration defines which rest services are hosted by which jvm. Furthermore we can add/remove services at runtime which enables us to "move" services between jvms.

We would need similar capabilities to dynamically add/remove REST services at runtime.

I read through https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11966 as well as https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/11415 which indicate that it is not possible to have multiple Applications in Quarkus. I have not found a way of manually adding removing REST services in https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive or https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json#creating-your-first-json-rest-service to one application at runtime.

I also tried to find a hint in the RESTEasy documentation but had no luck.

How can we address this topic - is there a way to do this within quarkus itself or do we need to implement something custom - and if - what would be a good starting point to look at?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way in Quarkus to run to different applications, you can however exclude certain classes from being processed.

The easiest way is to use `@IfBuildProfile` and `@EndpointDisabled` as mentioned [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#includeexclude-jakarta-rest-classes).

There is also the more brute-force way of [quarkus.class-loading.removed-artifacts](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.class-loading.removed-artifacts)

Comment: how will quarkus behave if i use the `@EndpointDisabled` annotation and change the value during runtime. If i include it per default and then someone decides to "stop" it and will it be stopped by quarkus? Or is this annotation only considered during startup?

Comment: What do you mean by `someone dedides to stop it`?

Comment: Our application configuration currently allows us to stop an internal worker which provides the rest endpoints but the jvm keeps running when a administrator stops the worker thread.

Comment: In Quarkus all metadata (configuration, annotations, etc) are only considered at build time and/or startup time.